# Objective-C: Expected a type error

Tags: ios, objective-c, types

I am trying to follow a tutorial for using a stylesheet from Nick Kuh's book *"iPhone App Development"*.  The stylesheet header file is throwing:

> "Expected a type"

errors which I think normally reflects a circular problem.  However, in this case the only import is to Foundation.h.  (The implementation file, btw, does not throw any errors and seems to be fine.)  Here is the header file in its entirety.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum : int {
    IDLabelTypeName = 0,
    IDLabelTypeBirthdayDate,
    IDLabelTypeDaysUntilBirthday,
    IDLabelTypeDaysUntilBirthdaySubText,
    IDLabelTypeLarge
}
IDLabelType;

@interface IDStyleSheet : NSObject
+(void)initStyles;

+(void)styleLabel:(UILabel *)label withType:(IDLabelType)labelType;//throws red error

+(void)styleTextView:(UITextView *)textView;//throws red error
+(void)styleRoundCorneredView:(UIView *)view;//throws red error


@end
```

Can anyone see why these errors are occurring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UILabel`, `UITextView` ... are defined in the UIKit framework, therefore you have to

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

(which then implicitly imports Foundation). You can also use the
more modern "module" syntax:

```
@import UIKit;
```

Comment: That did it.  So I gather I can take out import of foundation?

Comment: @user12345: Yes, UIKit already includes Foundation. (But it does no harm if you leave it.)